# Trying to increment by 1 every time the page is viewed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to figure out how to update the field by incrementing +1 each time the page is visited and if it has never been visited then add it to the DB.

Currently, this is what I have got but it does not seem to do much. I must have gone wrong somewhere and I have not yet implemented the part where if the page has never been viewed then create a new object in the array which is stored in the database.

Little note: Where I created the map they do match with the same ID if I view the page with the same ID as the one stored in the database but no increment happens.

```
exports.pageVisitCount = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById({
    _id: req.userData.userId
  }, 'visits', function (err, pageVists) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(401).json({
        message: "Error Occured!"
      })
    } else {
      const pageCounts = pageVists.visits;
      pageCounts.map(page => {
        const postViewed = req.body.postId;
        if (page.postId.toString() === postViewed) {
          User.findByIdAndUpdate({
              _id: req.userData.userId
            }, {
              $set: {
                visits: [{
                  "postId": postViewed,
                  $inc: { visitCount: 1 }
                }]
              }
            }, {
              upsert: false
            },
            (err) => {
              if (err) {
                res.status(401).json({
                  message: "Error Occured!"
                })
              } else {
                res.status(200).json({
                  message: "Update successful!"
                })
              }
            });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

This is the schema I am using:

```
const visitsSchema = new Schema ({
  postId: {
    type: String
  },
  visitCount: {
    type: Number
  }
})

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  answers: {
    type: String
  },
  visits: [visitsSchema]
});
```

Any feedback would be highly appreciated, I would like to mention that I am new to backend, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using the map to filter the `visits` after querying the `visits` of the user under consideration, I suggest you let mongodb do that for you. In this case you first do a find based on both the user id and the postId. If you get a record matching both criteria you are sure you can easily update the user visits by incrementing  the particular `visits` `visitCount` by 1.

Otherwise i.e. if they don't match any records then since u might be using a valid user id then such user has not visited such post. So you now create a new visit with the postId and initialize its visitCount to 1 (Although we intend to create, but since its a subdocument you'll need use `$push`). Enough of the talking try the code below.

```
exports.pageVisitCount = (req, res, next) => {
    User.findOne({
      _id: req.userData.userId, "visits.postId": req.body.postId
    }, 'visits.$', function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(401).json({
          message: "Error Occured!"
        });
      } else {

        if(user == null){
           User.findByIdAndUpdate({
              _id: req.userData.userId
           }, {
                $push: {
                   visits: {
                      "postId": req.body.postId,
                      visitCount: 1
                   }
                }
           },  function (err) {
             if(err) 
                return res.status(401).json({
                   message: "Error Occured when creating new visit!"
                })
             return res.status(200).json({
                message: "Success"
             })
           })
        }

        User.update({
            _id: req.userData.userId, "visits.postId": req.body.postId
        }, {
              $inc: { "visits.$.visitCount":  1 }
        },(err) => {
           if (err) {
              res.status(401).json({
                 message: "Error Occured!"
              })
           } else {
              res.status(200).json({
                 message: "Update successful!"
              })
           }
        });
      }
    });
};
```